# Numpad Buttons Panel

Tags: python, scripting, panel

A question arose recently regarding the numpad.

Below is the code that produces panel shown in the image

[image]

Have used a 3 column column flow and added the extra row and column with double sized keys.

The alignment would be better if the box layout wasn't used, however would like to keep the margins around the buttons that using boxes creates.

however, with the buttons in boxes its difficult without tweaking (double width or double height)  to get the alignment right.

Be keen to hear from `UILayout` gurus on how they would write this.

*Note the labels are out of order can be corrected later.*

```
import bpy


class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        x1 = layout.row(align=True)
        c1 = x1.column()
        c2 = x1.column()
        cf = c1.column_flow(columns=3, align=True)
        for key in sum(
            (
            ("NL", "/", "*"), 

            tuple(map(str, range(1, 10)))
            ),
            tuple()
            ):
                
            cf.box().operator("wm.splash", text=key)

        c2.box().operator("wm.splash", text="-")

        box = c2.box()
        box.scale_y = 2
        box.operator("wm.splash", text="-")
        box = c2.box()
        box.scale_y = 2
        box.operator("wm.splash", text="-")
        
        row = c1.row()
        box = row.box()
        box.scale_x = 2
        box.operator("wm.splash", text="-")
        box = row.box()
        box.operator("wm.splash", text="-")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what this is supposed to be. Are you making code to draw a numberpad in 3D or maybe grease pencil, or are you trying to create a user interface numberpad to replace the keyboard?

Comment: One concept could involve mapping the assigned blender keymap binding operator  to the  buttons (or demonstrating that they are free, or temporarily assigning something different)..  Basically tho  the question is re getting the layout right.

Comment: In that case, I’m not sure this is the right stack to exchange this question on.

Comment: Have no idea why you think that. Basically think of it as 17 blender operator buttons laid out to look like the numpad.

Comment: OK. Then you are trying to create a user interface numpad to replace the keyboard?

Comment: All right, I understand. I just wanted to make sure I knew what you were trying to create here in terms of whether I need to tell you about grease pencil or GUI API.  As it is, I know nothing about the GUI API. Sorry 